# Cannot type a HOC to add default props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a higher order component to add default props to a component. Those default props can be overridden.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
type VehicleProps = {
  wheels: number;
  brand: string;
};

const Vehicle:React.FC<Vehicle> = props => ...

const Car = setDefaultProps(Vehicle)({wheels:4})
// Car should have type React.FC<{brand:string, wheels?:number}> with wheels defaulting to 4
```

[Here is my implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChy0IA7AZ3hqRgBElMUBXAGxgAUcwacALxwAPHwgCANAD4AFAGFckKkiowAXImIwAdADEF4-jRkBKYTLGk4cANJwkADxhqAJoIDWSAJ4RMcBICpPI2cG6sHNxBNFo8wGiexpI0UvYypBZCVgDeYTA+YEhwLGxcvCbCcAVF-uGR5TEA3PmFxfrAVCicMVUAsijeAPJgMMDU3cnScN5+AaVRFSkyLbZEMOxQVHByYCZaHV09JllWokrg1GrwObp3EWXRJgC+cLd3eymvAPQrpM8tUg1YoDYajcZHKapOAjMYTY4pRwudxeXx1GJWER5WwAbQcnRh4PhMQAugBqAD8cRMeJJLVeADIwkMQMAYFC0rCId0MS0gA) of setDefaultProps

I get the error

> 'Props' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
> unrelated to 'Pick<Props, K> & { [K in K]+?: Props[K] | undefined; } &
> Omit<Props, K>'.

What am I missing out on ?

Comment: Why don't you just use destructurization in this way: ```const Component = ({ wheel = 4 }) => <div>Amount of wheel: { wheel }</div>``` ?

Comment: Recomposing props in HOCs gives this error really frequently.  Sometimes I am able to look at it and see the edge case where it wouldn't actually match the type.  But you are basing this on the key `K` so there's no chance of narrowing a value.  I can get the error `Type 'Pick<Props, K> & Omit<Props, K>' is not assignable to type 'Props'.` and I'm scratching my head a bit on that one.

Comment: Declaring the types `DefaultProps` and `FinalProps` inside of a function seems weird, though it does seem to work.  You don't need `typeof defaultProps` because you already know that the type of the variable is `Pick<Props, K>`.  You can just do `return (props: Partial<Props> & Omit<Props, K>) =>`

Comment: The easy solution is to assert: `return (props: Partial<Props> & Omit<Props, K>) => <Component {...{ ...props, ...defaultProps } as Props} />;` but I'd love to figure out how to avoid that!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
const wheelHOC = (wheel) => WrappedComponent => () => {

  return <WrappedComponent
    wheel={ wheel | 4 }/>;
};

const Component = (props) => {
  return <div>I have { props.wheel } wheels</div>
}

const WheelsDefault = wheelHOC()(Component)
const WheelsCustom = wheelHOC(5)(Component)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WheelsDefault/>
      <WheelsCustom/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This a question about a Typescript error and your code doesn't have any Typescript typings.